# Music app not syncing with OneDrive music folder

Tags: music, onedrive, xbox-music

I have a Windows phone, and I have music in my Music folder in OneDrive, and it displays on Windows 10 Xbox Music, but for some reason it's not synchronizing to my mobile Xbox Music. Xbox Music mobile is just saying "It's lonely in here..." Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the Xbox Music settings on your phone? There you should be able to enable streaming music from the cloud.

Comment: I have, it's definitely checked. Also nice name ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. It turns out the OneDrive and Music apps on my phone were outdated. Updating them fixed the issue and Music was able to access my library on OneDrive.